# Set a Column in Pivot Table as Percentage of Another

Tags: excel, pivot-table

How can make a column to be a percentage of another column in pivot table? For example, in the following.[image]

I want set the second column as the following percentages `1/1`, `44/46`, `459/465` etc. For the third column, I want it to appear as the percentages 
`1/1`. `41/44` and so on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe what you want is a calculated field.

From the pivot table "Options" menu for Office 2010 or before or the "Analyze" menu for office 2013 or after, select "Fields, Items and Sets" -> "Calculated Field."

In the Name box, name it whatever you want ("% of SLA Met").

In the Formula Box, you can click on the fields to have them brought up, and it will end up looking something like this:

```
='Responded SLA Met'/'Ticket Nbr'
```

That said, you can't really do a "sum / count" -- you can, but it won't do what you want.  So, you will probably have to add a column with all 1's in it (call it ticket count) and then use the sum of that as the denominator:

```
='Responded SLA Met'/'Ticket Count'
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! Yes, I have to create a helper column `Ticket Count` like you wrote.

Comment: you are lifesaver

Answer (score 2):

In newer Excel menu `Analyze -> Fields, Items, & Sets -> Calculated Field...`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In excel 2016 is possible to put formula inside e.x.

=COUNT(id)/SUM(valid_license)

[image]